# webpack ERROR :You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have tried many ways, I searched stackoverflow, still can not resolve.
I'm a react newbie.

the error :

```
ERROR in ./public/js/index.jsx
Module parse failed: /home/m/react/r-chat/front/public/js/index.jsx Line  3: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| /*'use strict';*/
| 
| import React, { Component, ProTypes } from 'react';
| import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory, hashHistory } from   'react-router';
| import Avatar from './components/avatar.jsx';
```

And my webpack file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry:  './public/js/index.jsx',
    output: {
    path: './build',
    filename: "bundle.js"
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015','react']
            }
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a loader for .jsx. Since you are using .jsx files, the .js loader will not work for that.

change

```
{
            test: /\.js?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015','react']
            }
        }
```

to

```
{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015','react']
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Jour no problem! Webpack is pretty complex and can be difficult to figure out

Answer (score 1):

You see in your loaders of the webpack config you are testing for js? You need to add it for JSX and use an appropiate loader for it.

babel can do this for you via babel-loader: https://github.com/babel/babel-loader

All you need to do is as the x into the test, like so:

```
loaders: [
    {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
            presets: ['es2015','react']
        }
    }
]
```